# Android when screen dims add a layer above everything to consume the onclick

Tags: android, screen, layer, drawerlayout

In my app I want when the screen dims to add a layer above everything so when the users taps on screen the dimness will be gone and then he can use the app. If I dont do this when the screen is dimmed and the user taps on screen he will activate something in the app.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<!-- The main content view -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/radio_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/disc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp" />
```

this is my layout. When the screen dims i make the disc visible and when the user touches something on screen I make it View.gone. The problem is that the click on the disc is also activating something on my content frame fragment.

Is there a way to make it now happen? I want the click to activate only the disc onclickhandler not anything else. Or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how to do this. The trick is to have an onclickListener on the view itself. I was just making it disappear while I had to also get the click.

```
private final Runnable disconnectCallback = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                disconnect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }));

    }
};

private static final Handler disconnectHandler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    }
};

public void resetDisconnectTimer() {
    disconnectHandler.removeCallbacks(disconnectCallback);
    disconnectHandler.postDelayed(disconnectCallback, 3000);

}

public void stopDisconnectTimer() {
    disconnectHandler.removeCallbacks(disconnectCallback);
}

@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    resetDisconnectTimer();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    resetDisconnectTimer();
}
```

and in onCreate i have this

```
 disconnect = findViewById(R.id.disc);
    disconnect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            disconnect.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });
```

in my previous attempt i was making the disconnect "gone" inside the handler. Now i have an onclick listener on this.